# How to paging html elements by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html elements like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="box">Box 1</div>
    <div class="box">Box 2</div>
    <div class="box">Box 3</div>
    <div class="box">Box 4</div>
    <div class="box">Box 5</div>
    <div class="box">Box 6</div>
    <div class="box">Box 7</div>
    <div class="box">Box 8</div>
</div>
```

I want to use jQuery to make a pagination for these elements and in the script I can modify numbers of elements per page, for example:
`num_per_page = 4` then page 1 will show `box 1` to `box 4` and page 2 will show `box 5` to `box 8`.

Comment: have you tried anything? share a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I just tried some jquery plugins but they are not flexible, i've just studied jquery and don't know a lot to do this, can you give me some suggestion and i will do it by myself

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with the code that you have tried http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I don't have an idea to do, can you give me a suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do,

```
var noOfBoxesPerPage = 3;
var totalPages = Math.ceil($(".content .box").length / noOfBoxesPerPage);
$(".content .box").hide();
$(".content .box:lt(" + noOfBoxesPerPage + ")").show();
for (i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
  $("#page").append("<span>" + i + "</span>");
}
$("#page").on("click", "span", function() {
  $(".content .box").show();
  var ltCount = ($(this).index()) * noOfBoxesPerPage;
  var gtCount = ($(this).index() + 1) * noOfBoxesPerPage;
  $(".content .box:lt(" + ltCount + ")").hide();
  $(".content .box:gt(" + (gtCount - 1) + ")").hide();
});
```

[**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/175/)

This will create pages as well as page indexes

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice)

```js
var num_per_page = 4;
//then page 1 will show box 1 to box 4 
// note, `.slice()` uses a 0-based index, 
// element at index `3` would be fourth from 0
$(".content .box").slice(0, num_per_page -1).show()
// and page 2 will show box 5 to box 8.
.end().slice(num_per_page).hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="content">
    <div class="box">Box 1</div>
    <div class="box">Box 2</div>
    <div class="box">Box 3</div>
    <div class="box">Box 4</div>
    <div class="box">Box 5</div>
    <div class="box">Box 6</div>
    <div class="box">Box 7</div>
    <div class="box">Box 8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it